# Componentes html guardar codificacion a utf8

Tags: html, angular, typescript, utf-8

Estoy usando angular y visual studio 19, y sucede que al momento de imprimir una lista local de un array se empieza a visualizar con caracteres extraños, cabe mencionar que mi index.html global cuenta con etiqueta charset="utf-8" y con la etiqueta content,

Lo raro es que si pongo palabras directo en el componente html, esos caracteres raros no aparecen, únicamente aparecen cuando los cargo en my typescript y trato de imprimirlos en el html, adicionalmente guarde mis archivos html y ts con la opción de "save with encoding" y los cambie a "with signature utf8" pero el problema es que aunque esten firmados se siguen viendo los caracteres raros en componentes, específicamente donde hago una lista de items en typescript y trato de imprimirla con un for en el html

Alguna alternativa para solventar esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualización código:

En esté caso la opción México aparece así en el html  MÃ©xico de igual forma es un dropdown como el que se muestra en la foto

```
export class RegistrationDataStepComponent {

  public countries = [
    { value: 'mexico', label: 'México', code: 'MX' },
    { value: 'usa', label: 'Estados Unidos', code: 'USA' }
  ];
}
```

Pasa como parametro a un componente dropdown que reciclo

```
 <app-dropdown [label]="'COUNTRY'" [items]="countries"></app-dropdown>
```

componente TS dropdown recibo los valores:

```
export class DropdownComponent
{

  @Input() public items: any = [];

}
```

HTML

```
<ng-container>
      <div #optionsContainer class="options-container">
        <div *ngFor="let item of items" >
          <input type="radio" class="radio" name="category" />
          <label >{{ item.label | translate }}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
</ng-container>
```

`item.label` usa un pipe que en general es para traducir a EN o ES, solo eso, pero `item.label` trae en si el valor de mi array (countries.label = 'México' pero lo muestra así MÃ©xico)

Comment: Hola. Comparte el codigo de .ts y el template para mirar, asi seguramente te podriamos ayudar.

Comment: cargue de forma resumida el componente ts y como lo imprimo en el html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la primera es que México tiene tilde y puede ser que el problema sea con la etiqueta META o puede que el problema sea directamente con el pipe de translate.

1. Puedes probar cambiando la meta de charset a ISO:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />`

2. la otra posible solucion viene del pipe de translate: Seguramente tienes implementado para eso @ngx-translate en caso de que asi sea, esta implementacion requiere un archivo json para cada idioma, este json es un diccionario en donde estan las palabras y sus traducciones, seria agregar la palabra y como quieres traducirla:

   `src/assets/i18n/en.json`

   `{ "México" : "México" }`

Incluso quizas en la traduccion debas incluir la codificacion especial de tildes:

`{ "México": M&eacutexico}`

3. En alguna epoca lejana (cuando php reinaba y SublimeText era algo que debias piratear) los server VPS traducian y se cargaban cosas como las meta etiquetas, los viejos usabamos meta etiquetas a la mala en los form:

`<form class="form" id="myForm" accept-charset="utf-8">`

Espero que algo de esto te ayude!

Happy Coding!